# Как импортировать  из  github?

Tags: android, github, java

Как импортировать из github? Я хочу импортировать вот эту библиотеку - [ссылка](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid). Я копирую 
из com папки antonyt и roomorama в папку com в моем проекте, но там еще нужно кучу данных из xml разметки.

Comment: @eldqs вы сами то поняли свой вопрос?

Comment: Так скопируйте и разметку, а вообще надо поискать, есть ли у них библиотека в репозитории для gradle, это избавит вас от анальной кары с файлами и т.д.

Comment: @ua6xh может, его проект скопировать надо куда-то?

Comment: @ua6xh извиняюсь, не работал интернет, сейчас работает, но я не понимаю, куда он скачал, не нашел, где находится эта библиотека и как он нашел именно эту библиотеку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам повезло, подключите просто библиотеку в gradle.

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.roomorama%22%20AND%20a%3A%22caldroid%22

UPD: блин, там же даже в инструкции написано "`For Android Studio user: add compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.7' to your gradle build file.`"

Comment: @ua6xh а что(весь проект?) и куда(в моем проекте) скопировать перед тем как ставить зависимость.

Comment: а по вашей ссылке это библиотеки, которые для maven, нормально ли будет использоваться в grable

Comment: @eldqs - ничего не надо копировать, просто вставляете строчку `compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.7'` в файл сборки gradle и всё само куда надо скопируется с сервера и будет использоваться как надо.

Comment: @eldqs - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.roomorama/caldroid/1.1.7 для всего есть настройки для репозитория

Comment: @ua6xh я подставил compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.7' грабл написал, что ошибка failed to find 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.7'

Comment: @eldqs гра**д**л

Comment: @eldqs - покажите весь файл градл

Comment: @ua6xh apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kz.tanikin.vid"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.7'
}